# pdfclown highlighting doesn't work for some pdf files

Tags: pdfclown

I am using the pdfclown library to highlight some text inside the pdf file but for some reason, I get nullpointerexception error when I run TextHighlightSample.

```
 [java] java.lang.NullPointerException
 [java]     at java.util.Hashtable.hash(Hashtable.java:239)
 [java]     at java.util.Hashtable.put(Hashtable.java:519)
 [java]     at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.fonts.SimpleFont.onLoad(SimpleFont.java:139)
 [java]     at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.fonts.Font.load(Font.java:738)
 [java]     at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.fonts.Font.<init>(Font.java:351)
 [java]     at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.fonts.SimpleFont.<init>(SimpleFont.java:62)
 [java]     at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.fonts.TrueTypeFont.<init>(TrueTypeFont.java:68)
 [java]     at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.fonts.Font.wrap(Font.java:253)
 [java]     at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.FontResources.wrap(FontResources.java:72)
 [java]     at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.FontResources.wrap(FontResources.java:1)
 [java]     at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.ResourceItems.get(ResourceItems.java:119)
 [java]     at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.objects.SetFont.getResource(SetFont.java:119)
 [java]     at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.objects.SetFont.getFont(SetFont.java:83)
 [java]     at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.objects.SetFont.scan(SetFont.java:97)
 [java]     at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.ContentScanner.moveNext(ContentScanner.java:1330)
 [java]     at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.ContentScanner$TextWrapper.extract(ContentScanner.java:811)
 [java]     at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.ContentScanner$TextWrapper.<init>(ContentScanner.java:777)
 [java]     at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.ContentScanner$TextWrapper.<init>(ContentScanner.java:770)
 [java]     at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.ContentScanner$GraphicsObjectWrapper.get(ContentScanner.java:690)
 [java]     at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.ContentScanner$GraphicsObjectWrapper.access$0(ContentScanner.java:682)
 [java]     at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.ContentScanner.getCurrentWrapper(ContentScanner.java:1154)
 [java]     at org.pdfclown.tools.TextExtractor.extract(TextExtractor.java:633)
 [java]     at org.pdfclown.tools.TextExtractor.extract(TextExtractor.java:647)
 [java]     at org.pdfclown.tools.TextExtractor.extract(TextExtractor.java:647)
 [java]     at org.pdfclown.tools.TextExtractor.extract(TextExtractor.java:296)
 [java]     at org.pdfclown.samples.cli.TextHighlightSample.run(TextHighlightSample.java:56)
 [java]     at org.pdfclown.samples.cli.SampleLoader.run(SampleLoader.java:140)
 [java]     at org.pdfclown.samples.cli.SampleLoader.main(SampleLoader.java:56)
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The foreground issue

The foreground issue is that PdfClown in `SimpleFont.onLoad()` (while reading the **Widths** from the font dictionary into its own structures) assumes that it has a `glyphIndexes` entry for each `codes` value for a key from the **FirstChar**-based indices in the **Widths** array:

```
  if(glyphWidthObjects != null)
  {
    ByteArray charCode = new ByteArray(
      new byte[]
      {(byte)((PdfInteger)getBaseDataObject().get(PdfName.FirstChar)).getIntValue()}
      );
    for(PdfDirectObject glyphWidthObject : glyphWidthObjects)
    {
      int glyphWidth = ((PdfNumber<?>)glyphWidthObject).getIntValue();
      if(glyphWidth > 0)
      {
        Integer code = codes.get(charCode);
        if(code != null)
        {
          glyphWidths.put(
            glyphIndexes.get(code),         //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            glyphWidth
            );
        }
      }
      charCode.data[0]++;
    }
  }
```

If you check for `null` here, e.g. replacing

```
        if(code != null)
```

by

```
        if(code != null && glyphIndexes.get(code) != null)
```

you will get rid of the `NullPointerException`.

Usually there are `glyphIndexes` entries for all those values. Thus, usually you don't get the `NullPointerException` here. But PdfClown in its attempt to be able to extract as much as possible uses a mixture of information from the PDF objects and the embedded font objects, and there still seem to be some shortcomings in the coordination of those information, e.g. in case of your document:

### The background issue

While constructing a `TrueTypeFont` object for the font *SourceSansPro-Regular* PdfClown

- (`Font.load`) tries to read a **ToUnicode** map to get a mapping from character codes to Unicode and put it into `codes`; unfortunately the font has no **ToUnicode** map; thus, `codes` remains `null`;
- (`OpenFontParser` construction in `TrueTypeFont.loadEncoding` initially called by `SimpleFont.onLoad`) tries to read information from the embedded font file; among other data it retrieved a mapping 32..213 -> 0..44 mapping character codes to in-font glyph indices;
- (still in `TrueTypeFont.loadEncoding` initially called by `SimpleFont.onLoad`) sets the font object's `glyphIndexes` member to that map; if there was a `codes` mapping already now, this would be used here to change the mapping to a mapping Unicode -> 0..44; but `codes` is `null` (see above), so `glyphIndexes` remains as is;
- (still in `TrueTypeFont.loadEncoding` initially called by `SimpleFont.onLoad`) as there is no `codes` mapping yet, it creates one based on the **MacRomanEncoding** entry from the PDF font dictionary;
- (still in `TrueTypeFont.loadEncoding` initially called by `SimpleFont.onLoad`) if there were no `glyphIndexes` yet, it would derive one from the current `codes` mapping and the **Widths** array; but we already have one, so it remains as is;
- (`SimpleFont.onLoad`) finally it tries to put the contents of the PDF font dictionary's **Widths** array into its `glyphWidths` map. The code (see above) assumes that `glyphIndexes` is a mapping of Unicode codes and, therefore, translates them using `codes` first. Unfortunately `glyphIndexes` here is not from Unicode codes but from character codes. Thus the failure observed above occurs.

Font extraction in PdfClown 0.1.3 is in need of clean-up. It tries to make use of information from both the PDF objects and the embedded fonts (which is a good idea) but for some situations like here shoots itself in the foot.

But it's still an early 0.x version after all, so some issues are to be expected...

Comment: hmm, I am still getting the same error message after putting in the replacement. if(code != null && glyphIndexes.get(code) != null)
            {
              glyphWidths.put(
                glyphIndexes.get(code),
                glyphWidth
                );
            } This is the only change I made.

Comment: Ate you sure you are using the changed library? After all that change prevents a `null` key which is the cause of that NPE.

Comment: Sorry. It was a mistake on my part. Problem resolved.